# tableview max width constraint

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I'm trying to set a max width on a tableview inside the default tableview controller in the storyboard. I'm not able to just set a <= width constraint for some reason it's greyed out in xcode.

I would just create a custom tableview inside my view but I've configured somethings that won't work that way with scroll without some work.

I'm trying to restrict the width for a scrolling feed with images so the ipad version isn't full screen. Just max say like 700 or something, any idea how to do that?

Standard xcode tableview controller
[image]

custom table view in view controller
[image]

This kind of worked, but it jumps into place and shows black bars on the side.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    if bounds.width > 414 {
        tableView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(600)
        tableView.center.x = bounds.size.width / 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't alter the frame of the UITableView of a UITableViewController because it is the root view of the controller.  If you want a UITableView to not take up the full width then you should create a UIViewController and add the UITableView to that.  If you do that the UIViewController will have its own UIView which is the root.

You say you are trying to set up your app so that it doesn't occupy the full screen on an iPad just 700 wide.  Unfortunately you can't do that you apps main window always takes up the entire display so even if you have a root view that was transparent you won't see the main iOS interface through it as your main window will block it (I think it would be black).

Comment: Thanks for the response. That does make sense, but It does seem like I can target it some.
tableView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(500) is restricting it, if I can just center that somehow. I only want the table to be smaller the rest of the app can be full size.

Comment: Ok in that case you have to manually add your own UITableView as the one provided in the UITableViewController must take up the entire area allocated to that view controller.  You have two options really 1) add the UITableView to a UIViewController (no point in using a UITableViewController anymore) or 2) Replace the UITableViewController with another standard UIViewController and then add the UITableViewController as a child view controller of that.

Comment: I'll be reworking it with option one, thanks for the advice. I did get it to constrain and center but like you said it ads black bars on the side and you see the width shift into place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can set the set the width using storyboard with special controllers, I could be wrong. But you could just do `tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true` and pick whatever constant you want, then use some conditional logic on the view.frame.width to change the constant value for specific situations

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't quite get that to work but I'm rebuilding it the correct way.